# Scaling UV map in Y Axis to fit image

Tags: uv, image

I added a lot of loopcuts to a "plane". Then I unwrapped the plane and added an image. But then I realized that the unwrap format does not match the shape of my picture. I tried to scale it by clicking <kbd>S</kbd>, but it scales the whole grid. I even tried scaling only to the y axis (<kbd>S</kbd>), but then it scales the bottom part of it as well. I only want the scale the top bit to match the picture not the bottom bit. How do I do this?

[image: UV view is on the right side and the original view is on the left side]

Comment: You should only unwrap your models _after_ you add the image.

Comment: Also, for this, you should be using the _Import Images as planes_ addon.

Comment: I don't see the word "Import Images" when clicking on "Image" in the UV view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to scale along the Y axis without moving the lower part :

- select all points
- position the cursor at (0, 0)
- scale along Y axis  ( <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> )

[image]

Comment: Yes, but how do I position my cursor at (0,0)?

Comment: @blueboy90780 write 0,0 in the highlighted  x, y   ( the right orange box "cursor location ")

Comment: thank you:D I couldn't find the icon to change "cursor to pivot" so I use the hotkey "." instead and continued the steps. Thank you for your help:D It worked

Answer (score 2):

It you unwrap again using **Project from View (Bounds)** your UV map will resize automatically to the image size.

[image]